# Combining the results/data from 3 separate SELECT statements (PLSQL)

Tags: sql, plsql

I am trying to combine the data from 3 SELECT statements.
First one would be showing "Present Inventory"
Second - "Goods in transit"
Third - "Goods in Production"

Finally the report should be something like this:

```
 [![Sample table][1]][1]
```

I tried using union/union all but it did not bring the desired result

Here are the separate queries that I have so far:

```
    1.
    select part_no, INV_PART_API.Get_Description(contract,part_no), location_no, qty_onhand, qty_reserved,
    (qty_onhand - qty_reserved) as "Available Qty"
    
    from INV_PART_IN_STOCK
    where location_no IN ('A','B','C', 'D') and qty_onhand > 0    -- Present
    
    
    2. 
    select part_no, 
    INVENTORY_PART_API.Get_Description(contract,part_no),
    location_no, 
    qty_onhand as "On Hand (In Transit)", 
    qty_reserved as "Reserved (In Transit)",
    (qty_onhand - qty_reserved) as "Available Qty (In Transit)"
    
    from INV_PART_IN_STOCK
    where location_no IN ('GIT') and qty_onhand > 0                -- In Transit
    
    
    
    3.
    select part_no, description, 
    buy_qty_due as "Qty in Production" from PURCHASE_ORDER_LINE
    where objstate in ('Confirmed', 'Released') and demand_code_db = 'Invent Order' and
    vendor_no = 11111         -- In Production
```

Thanks in advance.

Sorry if there is a similar question in the forum, I have searched for quite some time, but wasn't able to find something close.

Comment: It is not clear how you expect the results to be displayed. Can you build an example table of how the output should look?

Comment: looks like a 'simple' join (inner or left) of each query on the parts table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the first part will always return the part, you could left join on it. Otherwise it could be solved with full outer joins, or (way better), by driving the query on a central parts table, which I hope you have.

Anyway, using CTE's (with clause), it could be written like this, but each of the queries could also be inlined to have a bunch of joins between sub-selects.

```
with
  VW_INSTOCK as
  (
    select 
      part_no, INV_PART_API.Get_Description(contract,part_no) as part_description, location_no, qty_onhand, qty_reserved,
      (qty_onhand - qty_reserved) as "Available Qty"
    from INV_PART_IN_STOCK
    where location_no IN ('A','B','C', 'D') and qty_onhand > 0)
  ),
  
  VW_INTRANSIT as
  (
    select part_no, 
    INVENTORY_PART_API.Get_Description(contract,part_no),
    location_no, 
    qty_onhand as "On Hand (In Transit)", 
    qty_reserved as "Reserved (In Transit)",
    (qty_onhand - qty_reserved) as "Available Qty (In Transit)"

    from INV_PART_IN_STOCK
    where location_no IN ('GIT') and qty_onhand > 0                -- In Transit
  ),
  
  VW_INPROD as 
  (
    select 
      part_no, description, 
      buy_qty_due as "Qty in Production" 
    from PURCHASE_ORDER_LINE
    where 
      objstate in ('Confirmed', 'Released') and demand_code_db = 'Invent Order' and
      vendor_no = 11111         -- In Production
  )
select
  s.partno, s.part_description, s.location_no, s.qty_onhand, s.qty_reserved, s."Available Qty",
  t."On Hand (In Transit)", 
  t."Reserved (In Transit)",
  t."Available Qty (In Transit)",
  p."Qty in Production"
from
  VW_INSTOCK s
  left join VW_INTRANSIT t on t.part_no = s.part_no
  left join VW_INPROD p on p.part_no = s.part_no
```